# Can you import a whole website to Neo4J?

Tags: neo4j

Is it possible to add a whole website to Neo4J (easily), so that you have a nice presentation of all the pages and their connections?

We are working on a online book ([www.darwintsun.com](http://www.darwintsun.com/)), and we want to show the readers the connections between the different forms within Wing Tsun.

Imagine a whole wiki inside a Neo4J presentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Look at the `mirkonasato/graphipedia`: *a tool for creating a Neo4j graph database of Wikipedia pages and the links between them.*

https://github.com/mirkonasato/graphipedia